# How to execute common validation for every end point with package openapi-backend [Nodejs,TS]

Tags: javascript, node.js, openapi

I am using openapi-backend `npm i openapi-backend` where we can define endpoints and its `operationId`

```
openapi: 3.0.2
info:
  title: "Pet API"
  version: 1.0.0
paths:
  "/pets":
    get:
      operationId: getPets
      responses:
        "200":
          description: list of pets
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: array
                items:
                  $ref: "#/components/schemas/Pet"
components:
  schemas:
    Pet:
      type: object
      properties:
        id:
          type: string
        type:
          type: string
          enum: ["cat", "dog"]
        name:
          type: string
      required: ["id", "type"]
```

Intialization :-

```
import OpenAPIBackend from "openapi-backend";

// create api with your definition file or object
const api = new OpenAPIBackend({ definition: "./petstore.yml" });

// register your framework specific request handlers here
api.register({
  getPets: (c, req, res) => res.status(200).json({ result: "ok" }),
  getPetById: (c, req, res) => res.status(200).json({ result: "ok" }),
  notFound: (c, req, res) => res.status(404).json({ err: "not found" }),
  validationFail: (c, req, res) =>
    res.status(400).json({ err: c.validation.errors }),
});

// initalize the backend
api.init();
```

**But how can we define a method which can we can execute like `isRequestValid()`, since we don't have flexibility to define an array of methods in `operationID`. What is the best way to do in TS ?**